# Renew of your Shahada

Tags: evil-thoughts

What is the procedure for renewing of shahada? like you have been a Muslim but had some disbelief thoughts then an instant regret you repent ,you ask for forgiveness from Almighty Allah then do you need to do your shahada again. If yes, then do you have to do in front of witnesses or just say by your own self ???

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For more information about our site and the stackexchange model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Note that if you are praying you are repeating the shahadah at least 5 times a day. Why do you think one needs to renew the shahadah just for thoughts. What counts in Islam are the deeds.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Hadith which is narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him),

**that the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Allah, may He be glorified and exalted, will forgive my ummah for whatever crosses their minds so long as they do not act upon it or speak of it.”**

Al-Bukhaari (6491) and Muslim (131)

If youhave such thoughts, ignore them to the best of your ability as they are waswas from shaytaan.